# Unable to add ' ' to the Web site. Access is denied (550)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, deployment, ftp

When I try to publish the project through visual studio I get the "**Access is denied (550)**"  after googling the error I come to know that the issue is with ftp permission as it is read-only. But I am not able to see a permission property with read only in Visual Studio and unchecking it in order to give it full permission.

Comment: The user you're using to FTP files to the server does not have permission to over-write existing files or has lost its write permission all together. This is not a Visual Studio setting, this is a setting on your FTP server for your users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this sounds like a setting on the FTP site itself, not a Visual Studio issue.  The FTP account you are using probably does not allow you to write to it.

I like to publish to a directory on my computer and then work with my Systems Admin to determine the best way of getting the data to the server (e.g., he gives me access via both allow-write FTP accounts and remote desktop.).  Then I just physically move the files.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to give write permission in your FTP folder to the user you're using while deploying your app.

A more complete answer with step by step checking can be seen here: http://forums.asp.net/post/3966123.aspx

Comment: Microsoft subscribes to security by obfuscation philosophy. Windows will gladly tell you that you don't have permission, but won't tell you what needs permission and which permissions it needs. 

Consequently, I've seen users and even highly technical people turn permissions  off until the error goes away. It's no wonder Windows is so insecure. Nice job Microsoft!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Solved by ensuring that when you Publish>Connection, that the Passive Mode box is checked. Issue resolved